# How to click on a dropdown and select an option through Selenium and Java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu, webdriver

I am trying to click the dropdown button, code run successfully but dropdown button was not clicked in selenium.

```html
<select id="comp_drpdwn" data-select-id="f41d68e6-38b3-19cc-c392-3c9fc33690e8" class="initialized">
   <option value="0">Select Company</option>
   <option value="Acme~54sc234xb">Acme</option>
   <option value="Acme Bar &amp; Grill~TI17267302">Acme Bar &amp; Grill</option>
   <option value="Ball &amp; Chain~TI58377308">Ball &amp; Chain</option>
```

my code is :

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='comp_drpdwn']"));
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(element).click().build().perform();
```

Comment: How about providing some context? Without knowing the structure of the web page, nobody can tell whether your xpath makes sense or not.

Comment: Can you share URL of the web application?

Comment: @Buaban how i can share the url & credentials ?

Comment: @Saravanan just add them in your question. if it is a proprietary software, you may share more HTML. I guess it is not a simple select element.

Answer (score 0):

It is a select tag. You can use Select class of selenium.

For example to select the option Acme, try the following code.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='comp_drpdwn']"));
Select sel = new Select(element);
sel.selectByVisibleText("Acme");
```

Comment: i am trying above code but its displayed error like : org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated
  (Session info: chrome=67.0.3396.62)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.39.562718

Comment: You may need to be wait for the visibility of element.

Comment: When i am mouse over on element, displayed html is : <input type="text" class="select-dropdown" readonly="true" data-activates="select-options-f41d68e6-38b3-19cc-c392-3c9fc33690e8" value="R3PORTS, INC">

Comment: this is my latest code : WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
  WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input [@value='R3PORTS, INC']")));
  WebElement element1234 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input [@value='R3PORTS, INC']"));
  element1234.click();

Comment: displayed error is : displayed error is : org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element <input type="text" class="select-dropdown" readonly="true" data-activates="select-options-47eb660d-70d8-548b-7bfc-7d3d61d319b2" value="R3PORTS, INC"> is not clickable at point (223, 28). Other element would receive the click:

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='comp_drpdwn']"))); 
Select select = new Select(element);
select.selectByVisibleText("Acme");
```

Answer (score 0):

@Murthi's approach was pretty much in the right direction. As the element is a `<select>` element you have to use an instance of [**`Select`**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html) class. But it seems that the **value** and **VisibleText** property of the `option` tags contains dynamic text (e.g. `~54sc234xb`) and special characters (e.g. `&amp;`). So my take would be to use the [**`selectByIndex(int index)`**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html#selectByIndex-int-) method as follows:

```
WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@class='initialized' and @id='comp_drpdwn'][@data-select-id]"));
Select select = new Select(elem);
select.selectByIndex(1);
```

Comment: above code displayed error like : org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated

Comment: @Saravanan Can you update the question with a bit more of the outerHTML of the select node?